# I can not use AjaxControlToolkit in my projects

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I use MS visual studio 2008.But i can not use AjaxControlToolkit in my projects.
I can not AjaxControlToolkit  controls to my web forms.

Can you help me about this problem?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this???

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/30/asp-net-ajax-in-net-3-5-and-vs-2008.aspx

Personally I've downloaded the toolit, right click on the tools in VS, select "Add item", point to the DLL I've download and Voila.